# Date.now instead of a getTime not working

Tags: javascript, date, time, countdown

I am looking to improve my javascript skills but I need some help on some part.
I did a Countdown which is working but that's not the problem.

I am trying to use Date.now instead of getTime to improve script performance.
There is my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jq){
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get todays date and time
    var d = new Date();
    // Passer en UTC
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset());
    // Repasser en n'importe timezone (même si là, c'est plus intelligent de changer le script pour rester en UTC) :
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 8 * 60); // Ici GMT + 8, attention toutefois au DST s'il y en a dans ta timezone
    var countDownDate = getNextDayOfWeek(d,0,21);

    var now = d.getTime();
```

Thanks you for help!

Comment: If you want to use Date.now then use it like this: `Date(Date.now)`. It will return date and time like this: "Mon Aug 27 2018 14:54:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya that will return an invalid date.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.now` is a method of `Date`, so you should be good using `Date.now()`. If you want to manipulate the (current) date, use `new Date(Date.now())`

```js
let d = new Date(Date.now());
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var n = Date.now();

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

You just have to add it to the variable like this :

```
   var now =  Date.now();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
 var d = new Date();
 console.log(+d)
```